# 'arguments to path.join must be strings' typeerror during ember serve and ember build

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, typeerror, github-pages

I just started working on some ember tutorials and I wanted to try and make a gh-pages branch so I could host the project.  I was looking at tutorials on how to do so and made some changes to my config/environment.js.  I was following the steps from [ember-cli-github-pages](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-github-pages) but ran into some issues, so I deleted the branch and started to try again, however now I am getting the following error when I try to build or even run the server.

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
at Object.posix.join (path.js:488:13)
at AddonDiscovery.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon-discovery.js:107:24)
at Array.map (native)
at AddonDiscovery.discoverFromDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon-discovery.js:97:68)
at AddonDiscovery.discoverProjectAddons (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon-discovery.js:45:31)
at Project.discoverAddons (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:317:40)
at Project.initializeAddons (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:336:8)
at Project.eachAddonCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:389:10)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:34:13)
at CLI.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:35:26)
```

Still being quite new, I've searched throughout stackoverflow and Google to find a hint of what is going wrong and how to fix it but nothing so far. Here is what my environment.js file looks like

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        modulePrefix: '',
        environment: environment,
        baseURL: '/',
        locationType: 'auto',
        EmberENV: {
            FEATURES: {
                // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
                // e.g. 'with-controller': true
            }
        },

        APP: {
            // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
            // when it is created
        }
    };

    if (environment === 'development') {
        // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
    }

    if (environment === 'test') {
        // Testem prefers this...
        ENV.baseURL = '/';
        ENV.locationType = 'none';

        // keep test console output quieter
        ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
        ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

        ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    }

    if (environment === 'production') {

    }

    return ENV;
};
```

Any hint or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated or where I should look on how to get rid of this error.

I'm using mac os x

```
:> ember --version
version: 1.13.1
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.12.1
```

Update:

`ember serve` is now giving the same error on brand new project

Comment: I would suggest to reinstall ember-cli, but first delete npm cache clean and bower cache clean.

Comment: Thanks, I delete npm and bower cache and reinstalled ember, but now I am getting 'Uncaught Error: Could not find module /app'

I started a new project, started the server and now its serving at localhost:4200/project-name instead of the root